# Angular directive runs twice

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following html in my mainpage:

```
<div ui-view resource-loader></div>
```

My custom directive is resource-loader. When I load the main page it runs once. But when I navigate to mainpage.html#/page1 it runs again. My question is since it runs again does that mean that the resource-loader directive was removed when I navigated to page1 and then loaded again?

Directive code, nothing special:

```
Directives.directive('resourceLoader', function (Helper) {
return {
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        Helper.callingSomeFinction();

       }
}
```

});

Comment: Missed html:  <div ui-view resource-loader></div>

Comment: Check whether you are not including your directive twice.

Comment: Share your directive code.

Comment: That's all. Plus a bunch of links and script tags.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is loaded again.  When you use ui-view and you change state,  a new controller with its own scope is loaded.  As you can see in your directive,  it takes a scope.  This scope (because of your html) is the one from your state.  Therefore,  when the state changes there has to be a new directive.

Comment: Yes, I understand why a new scope is loaded. But still I am not sure why the same directive is loaded again if there is no reference to it in a template that is being currently loaded.

Comment: <div ui-view resource-loader></div> The ui-view in this line is the reference to it.  You can inspect the code and look for the ng-scope added by angular,  this way you should see that there is a scope associated to your ui-view and it is this scope that you bind to your directive. Which is why the directive is loaded again.